# CryptProtectData fails with NTE_BAD_KEYSET (0x80090016) error on Windows XP when run from the local service

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, cryptoapi

I'm using the following code from within my local service to scramble some sensitive data before it's saved in the `HKLM` key:

```
LPCTSTR pStr = L"This is a plaintext string!";

DATA_BLOB blobIn;
blobIn.pbData = (BYTE*)pStr;
blobIn.cbData = lstrlen(pStr) * sizeof(TCHAR);

DATA_BLOB blobOut = {0};

if(::CryptProtectData(&blobIn, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, CRYPTPROTECT_UI_FORBIDDEN, &blobOut))
{
    //Success, use encrypted byte array from blobOut.pbData

    ::LocalFree(blobOut.pbData);
}
```

Well, this works fine, except when run on Windows XP (from within my local service.) The [CryptProtectData](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380261%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) API fails with error code NTE_BAD_KEYSET (0x80090016).

Any idea how to make it work there?

Comment: The error `NTE_BAD_KEYSET` means either the keys don't exist or you do not have permission to access them. I'm guessing (though not certain) that the problem is related to the fact that you're trying to call this function from a service, but failing to specify the `CRYPTPROTECT_LOCAL_MACHINE` flag. Without that flag, the function is trying to encrypt the data using the current user's key. But there is no "current user" because you're calling it from a service.

Comment: @CodyGray: Two corrections. 1) Services have a current user account, it's `NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM` with the SID `S-1-5-18` and 2) if I use `CRYPTPROTECT_LOCAL_MACHINE` flag it kinda defeats the purpose... any user on that PC will be able to unscramble the data.

Comment: Hmm yeah, your #1 is true enough. I was slightly over-simplifying to avoid leaving a comment that was too long. Services run as the LocalSystem account unless you specifically specify a different in your service installer. The problem is, the LocalSystem account does not have a password. So although I am not absolutely certain, I am guessing that this may also mean that it does not have keys that can be used with the crypto APIs.

Comment: @CodyGray: No, I don't think that Crypto-API uses the password for encryption. Otherwise if a user changed it the encryption would break. Most certainly it uses user's SID. In either case, this method works on Vista and up. It fails only on Windows XP. That's why I'm asking.